# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found in Ubuntu 18.04 - HP Pavillion x360

Tags: networking, drivers, hp

Okay, so I've encountered yet another issue in my endeavor of "Installing Ubuntu to a brand new and clean HP System." I've tried many different potential solutions to this issue (from checking off the "Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware and additional media formats" TWICE to installing the appropriate drivers... again) however nothing seems to be working for me. I've even reinstalled Ubuntu to see if it would do anything.

I don't know what I could be doing wrong, because before I booted off Windows I was able to connect to the internet just fine. Currently have to plug my phone into the device to get any internet whatsoever.

After running the lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 command, was met with:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
```

After running the rfkill list command, was met with;

```
0:hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

That's it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: You wrote that you tried many solutions, but I can't imagine any solution without knowing your wireless hardware.

Comment: That was easy. Search AU by your network adapter model.

Comment: I'll give this a shot. Also how exactly would I do that? (The... searching by my network adapter model.) I'm sorry if I sound kinda stupid here.

Comment: Now you know your wireless adapter model: `Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821`. So you can find how to install drivers for it. You can't solve "Wi-Fi is not working" without it.

Comment: Ohhhh, alright! I'll see what I can do. Also will be looking into the solution you provided me. Here's to hoping this will actually work.